# Do two redirects in a web page

Tags: javascript, html, single-sign-on, jira, confluence

I am looking for ideas on how to do two redirects.  It is actually to get around a weak point of an add-on that is supposed to do sso (single signon).  Instead, the free MS Azure add-on for Jira/Confluence when you land on the home page has a button you have to click to initiate the sso part.  I want to bypass this since we are putting links in Jira/Confluence in another app that I want users to just click and go to those pages.

The idea was to have a web page that does first:

https://ourserver.com/jira/plugins/servlet/saml/auth
This then takes the user to the home page.  The home page is not where I want them to land though.  Instead, it would be a specific page like:

https://ourserver.com/jira/browse/CONF-3

Is there a way to have it go to the first link, and then redirect over to the desired location?

I see a lot on how to do redirects, but not sure how to do two.

Of course, if you know some way to do this within Jira/Confluence with application links or something like that, then that is good too.

Comment: You should use filter for redirection based on request url

Comment: Even if I had a filter (not sure to add to Jira/Confluence), it would still go to one thing url.  I need it to go the first so that login token is cached, and then go to the other.

Comment: As per my understanding, if you can set any parameter in saml request then you should try this. you can pass redirect url to saml request in 'AssertionConsumerURL' parameter, So response will be send to this url rather pre-define url.